3-band Equalizer circuit

Hello, I'm working on my pcb project-3 band equalizer. This is my circuit so far, it has 100Hz LPF, 1kHz BPF, and 4kHz HPF in parallel.
While it works well by passing the frequencies I want when I tested in breadboard, I'm not sure if it will work well when I implement this in PCB board and connect with speaker.
I see many people making simple EQ added capacitor in the input as DC block in order to reduce noise. Do I need to add this in my circuit too? Also, will it be sufficient to print out the sound? (My plan in to use LM324N op amp.) I'd be happy to grab some comments about any of this circuit.

Use an opamp follower at input. Should help input/output impedances. Don't forget decoupling capacitors at opamps supplies inputs.

Will 2.2uF capacitor will not enough for input dc blocking? Also I'm not sure the role of capacitors in the opamps supplies.

You have a "low value" of input impedance. Buffer should help really. And 2.2 uF would be enough for DC blocking after the buffer. Add one before. The power supply capacitor should also help with something like the "motorboating" effect ...
